# Do Minecraft monsters spawn on stairs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm building a house and using stairs for the look of the roof. Will monsters spawn up there at night (assuming I'm sufficiently far away)? Do I have to put torches up there to prevent that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not need to put torches up there. Passive mobs spawn on grass only (at least in grassy areas...), aggressive mobs spawn on cube-blocks only. No steps, no slabs etc.

*Edit*. As mentioned in comments, monster can be spawned in upside-down stairs, at least in 1.4.6 version (which is old, though)
Here you may check it for 1.8 version:

Comment: You may be right, but do you have any source for that in 1.5? Previously I had read that mobs didn't spawn on anything but *opaque* blocks, which let out blocks that were transparent (like leaves) and some that let light through (stairs, for some reason). However, now that stairs are *opaque* to light, will they spawn hostile mobs?

Comment: As stairs are opaque (they always were, by the way - they just had a flag set to not throw shadows), nope, hostile mobs do not spawn on stairs. Also, mobs _can_ spawn on leaves. Setting your graphics mode to 'fast' makes them opaque, allowing mobs to spawn on them. However, I have no sources for that, it is just experience I guess. You might want to check MCW, I would bet there is an article on mob spawning.

Comment: > Doesn't that just make the *texture* lose its transparency?  I'm sure light still passes through leaves when you have your graphics displaying in *fast* mode...

Comment: They don't spawn on "Glass, Ice, Stone Slabs, or other see-through or non-cube blocks". And "Since the graphics mode affects whether Leaves are see-through, it also affects spawning behavior" : http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Spawn#Enemy_Mobs .

Comment: For reference, mobs **will** spawn on upside-down stairs (however, you are unlikely to use them for a roof)

Comment: Well the issue with leaves has been fixed long ago. Also I suppose it never occured on server.

Comment: @IQAndreas Really? In that case it might be very much worth adding as an answer (in fact it's what actually brought me to this question). Do they also spawn on upside down slabs?

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows 10 Edition, today a skeleton spawned on the roof of a librarian's house, which is made of wooden stairs only.