# Can hostile mobs spawn on leaves in Minecraft Beta 1.8 or higher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Minecraft monsters spawn on stairs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21169/do-minecraft-monsters-spawn-on-stairs)
>   [Will monsters spawn on top of trees?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/will-monsters-spawn-on-top-of-trees)

Can hostile mobs spawn on leaves regardless of graphic mode (fast or fancy) in Beta 1.8.1?

I know this has been asked before for an older version of the game and the answer was yes if in fast mode, but since the game has changed so much since then, I'm wondering if the answer might be different now.

I'm asking because I'm building treehouses in the water in order to "ender-proof" them (as I don't like having to replace blocks the endermen stole/moved). So, do I need to add some light-source to the top of my trees or am I okay with just the regular tree-tops?

Comment: Okay. But there were several older questions dealing with the problem, so you would have to update all of them. Here's the link to the question that brought me here (not limited to leaves) : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21169/do-minecraft-monsters-spawn-on-stairs And here's a link to another one focusing on leaves: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/will-monsters-spawn-on-top-of-trees And I guess this one is also closely linked to it: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22241/whats-the-difference-between-the-fancy-and-fast-settings-in-minecraft

Comment: @nicky — The stairs question doesn't seem directly related, and the answer hasn't changed.  The fast-vs-fancy question was updated to reflect the current state of the game some time ago.  The monsters-on-trees question is an exact duplicate of this one, was already up-to-date, and I've just updated the accepted answer *again* to explicitly address mob spawning in current versions.  Does that address all of your concerns?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/will-monsters-spawn-on-top-of-trees,  and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22241/whats-the-difference-between-the-fancy-and-fast-settings-in-minecraft